# Storing rich text editor text and image value in database,GO

Tags: html, go, web-applications, rich-text-editor

Just the tittle basically, I'm learning GO by building web app using NextJS frontend. I am stuck at how to handle text and image data submitted from Quill editor. For example, the content field of my payload "content": "

...<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,...">...

". I understand that the image from the editor should be replaced with some sort of url and saved to content field of the table. The table in Postgres has Id, content and post_imageurl. Ultimately I want the frontend to query and render the content automatically.

I would like to understand what the standard is, and how to handle for example change of image storage services.